# Product Images are not showing in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9

picture not showing in Magento 
 
[image]

How to fix this error ?

Comment: did you checked in backend, did you selected radio buttons for base, thumbinal or small image ?

Comment: ok i can post question now.
Thank you so much.

Comment: We are no longer accepting answers from this account. See the Help Center to learn more.

What is the problem here ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you select the radio button of **Base Image** under the product Images tab from your admin panel.